# How to hire a vehicle using a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am creating a car hire service. I want to create a stored procedure for me to hire a vehicle. I want the hired in the vehicle table to turn yes, and for the user to input the vehicle id, user_id, hired from and hired till and for this to go the reservation table. I have made the procedure to turn the hired in the vehicle table to yes, but I think also want it to input the data to the reservation table at the same time.

Help, I'm so confused. Can this even be done??

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `hireVehicle`(in vehicle_id int)
begin
    update vehicle 
        set hired = 'yes'
    where vehicle_id = vehicleid;
end
```

Comment: what is your server MySQL or MS SQL?

Comment: This is really too broad - what you want here is a tutorial on how to update a database.  You need to look for parameterised queries, allowing you to pass in the data you need.  Also, if this is SQL-server (unclear from your tags) you should consider hired being a bit field (0/1) rather than a string 'yes'/'no'.

Comment: Don't looks like SQL Server.

Comment: It's got a MySQL tag....

Comment: If all you want to do is update 2 tables, you can definitely do that. Just add another update statement after that first one.

Comment: @MikeMiller: It also has a SQL Server tag.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have multiple statements in one stored procedure.

So you need to broaden the parameters passed in to include your new ones,

CREATE PROCEDURE `hireVehicle`(in vehicle_id int, in user_id int, in hireStart datetime, in hireEnd datetime)

You then need to add the other statement

Insert into Reservation(userid, vehicleid, hirestart, hireend)
values (...)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, as for me, ***you need 3 tables*** (**persons, vehicle and reservation**). Reservation table consists of ids from both tables persons and vehicle, dates etc. Inside your procedure you have to define just one insert to control this situation in your DB. [Here you can read about table relationships](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561)